# Generic to Specific list returns "Cannot cast error" in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using .NET 4.6 and I am trying to create a specific list from a generic one. 
Code(the generic list):`

```
var clients = (from a in accounts
                       group j by new
                       {
                           a.Code,
                           a.Name,
                           a.AddressLine1,
                           a.Postcode,
                           a.City,
                       }
                       into g
                       select new
                       {
                           g.Key.Code,
                           g.Key.Name,
                           g.Key.AddressLine1,
                           g.Key.PowerTools,
                           g.Key.Internetportal,
                           g.Key.Huisvestingsplanning,
                           g.Key.Werkplanning,
                           g.Key.Vervoersplanning
                       }).ToList();
```

The specific List(Customer.cs):

```
struct Customer
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public double PowerTools { get; set; }
    public double Internetportal { get; set; }
    public double Huisvestingsplanning { get; set; }
    public double Werkplanning { get; set; }
    public double Vervoersplanning { get; set; }
```

}

Conversion:

```
customers = clients.Cast<List<object>>().Select(x => new Customer(){
            Code = (string)x[0],
            Name = (string)x[1],
            Address = (string)x[2],
            PowerTools = (double)x[3],
            Internetportal = (double)x[4],
            Huisvestingsplanning = (double)x[5],
            Werkplanning = (double)x[6],
            Vervoersplanning = (double)x[7]}).ToList();
```

The error this conversion throws:
Unable to cast object of type **'<>f__AnonymousType6`8 [System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Double,System.Double,System.Double,System.Double,System.Double]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'.**

Thanks

Comment: Casting to List<object> is not possible. Just use clients.Select and change the strange x[..] code.

Comment: Your anonymous type is already strongly typed after your select, what is the use case? You can't cast directly to the type you want since you are creating an anonymous type which is completely disparate from the list type. You can transfer the items to a `List<T>` though... Can you explain why you are trying to do this, maybe you are misunderstanding something.

Comment: Why I am trying to create this: I have this query made in Linq that returns a generic List(from what I can understand)(clients) and I need it to be more specific like a List<Customer> so I can then manage this list of Customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to be trying to convert some object into a list of its properties - this isn't going to work, C# isn't JavaScript. It's doable, but completely unnecessary.

What you really need is to just use the anonymous type in the way it's meant to be used:

```
clients.Select(x => new Customer { Code = x.Code, Name = x.Name, ... }).ToList();
```

Depending on the actual LINQ provider you're using, it might even be possible to skip the middle man and select directly into your own type - consult the documentation.

Also, just for clarity - both of those lists are generic. The difference is that the first one is a generic list of an anonymous type, while the second one is a generic list of a named type.